# How to implement an interruptible time.sleep in Tornado?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, concurrency, tornado

I am writing a process (called the *requesting process*) which will send HTTP requests periodically, but can be interrupted by another thread/process (called the *main process*) at any time. Initially I was using a thread pool for the requests with a `multiprocessing.Event` object to wait for the appropriate delay before sending the next request:

```
# in the main process
poison_pill_event= multiprocessing.Event()

# pass "poison_pill_event" to the requesting process

# in the requesting process which sends requests every wait_interval seconds
poison_pill_event.wait(timeout=time_interval)
```

This would allow me to have an interruptible version of time.sleep(), in case I need to kill the process. Else, it would allow the code to continue running after the timeout.

Recently, I've found that given my required throughput and ressources, an async design is a better fitting alternative and I've tried using Tornado. Started by using [`gen.sleep`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/gen.html) as a non-blocking wait, but it can't be interrupted.
Then switched to using [Toro.Event's wait function](http://toro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/classes.html#event) to allow interruptions. However, Toro.Event's `delay` is different from multiprocessing.Event's `timeout` in that it raises a Timeout exception an thus discontinues execution. Also, I don't believe I can share it between processes, so I'm now trying to merge my main process with the requesting process, but that shouldn't be too difficult.

So my question is how can I reemulate the behavior I had with `multiprocessing.Event.wait` in Tornado?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need Toro anymore. Tornado 4.2 and later include all Toro's features.

Try something like this, with a Condition instead of an Event:

```
import datetime
import logging

from tornado import gen, options
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado.locks import Condition

condition = Condition()


@gen.coroutine
def waiter():
    for _ in range(10):
        yield condition.wait(timeout=datetime.timedelta(seconds=1))
        logging.info("Tick")


@gen.coroutine
def notifier():
    yield gen.sleep(4.5)
    logging.info("Notify")
    condition.notify()


@gen.coroutine
def runner():
    # Yield two Futures; wait for waiter() and notifier() to finish.
    yield [waiter(), notifier()]


options.parse_command_line()  # Configures logging.
IOLoop.current().run_sync(runner)
```

You'll see log output like:

```
[I 160712 12:00:28 foo:15] Tick
[I 160712 12:00:29 foo:15] Tick
[I 160712 12:00:30 foo:15] Tick
[I 160712 12:00:31 foo:15] Tick
[I 160712 12:00:31 foo:21] Notify
[I 160712 12:00:31 foo:15] Tick
[I 160712 12:00:32 foo:15] Tick
[I 160712 12:00:33 foo:15] Tick
[I 160712 12:00:34 foo:15] Tick
[I 160712 12:00:35 foo:15] Tick
[I 160712 12:00:36 foo:15] Tick
```

Notice how, in the second that "Notify" was logged, there are two "Ticks", but otherwise Ticks occur only once per second.

Comment: Works great! A note to all using this: `condition.wait` takes a timedelta. However, though it will not raise an error if you give it a numerical value, it will not work the same way. It seems to consider the numerical value as an absolute time value with the same reference point as `IOLoop.time`. Thank you once again @A2J for the help.